# Creating a function that contains a while loop

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I am new to PHP and trying to learn it by creating a database of all my jobs (I'm a freelance designer).  I have created the code below to generate a table to display all jobs where the description contains logo which works fine and generates several rows....

```
<?php
$logojobs = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM hlgd_projects WHERE description LIKE '%logo%'", $connection);
?>

<a href="index.php?report=logo">View logo jobs</a>

<?php
if ($report == 'logo') {         
echo "<h1>Logo jobs</h1>";
echo "<table id='report'>
    <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Lead</th>
     <th>Start</th>
     <th colspan='2'>Codes</th>
     <th>Client</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>Fee</th>
     <th>Contact</th>
     <th colspan='2'>Invoice</th>
     <th>Paid</th>
    </tr>";
 while ($logojob = mysql_fetch_array($logojobs)) { 
    echo "<tr>
        <td class='id'>" . $logojob['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['status_id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['lead_id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['date_start'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['code_lead'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['code_hlgd'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['client'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['description'] . "</td>
        <td>&pound;" . $logojob['fee'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['contact'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['invoice'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $logojob['date_inv'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $logojob['date_paid'] . "</td>      
    </tr>";             
 }  
 echo "</table>";        
}
?>
```

However I would like to be able to generate reports for lots of different things and so would like to create a function to generate the table and pass the relevant arguments each time.  I've done this as follows but it only generates the first row so I presume it's ignoring the while?  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or how to better put the code above into a function?

```
<?php
function report_bytype($title,$job_set,$job_name) {
  $reporthead = "<h1>$title</h1>
    <table id='report'>
    <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Lead</th>
     <th>Start</th>
     <th colspan='2'>Codes</th>
     <th>Client</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>Fee</th>
     <th>Contact</th>
     <th colspan='2'>Invoice</th>
     <th>Paid</th>
    </tr>";
  while ($job_name = mysql_fetch_array($job_set)) { 
    $reportrows = "
        <tr>
        <td class='id'>" . $job_name['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['status_id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['lead_id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['date_start'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['code_lead'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['code_hlgd'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['client'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['description'] . "</td>
        <td>&pound;" . $job_name['fee'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['contact'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['invoice'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['date_inv'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $job_name['date_paid'] . "</td>     
    </tr>";             
  }                             
  $reportfoot = "</table>"; 
  $reporttable = $reporthead . $reportrows . $reportfoot;
  echo $reporttable;
  return $reporttable; 
}
?>

<?php
if($report == 'logo') {
report_bytype("logo",$logojobs,$logojob);
}
if($report == 'stationery') {
report_bytype("stationery",$stationeryjobs,$stationeryjob);
}
?>
```

Many thanks in advance,
Helen

Comment: How do you initialize `$logojobs` and `$stationeryjobs`?

Comment: set register_globals to "off" in your php.ini config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
while ($job_name = mysql_fetch_array($job_set)) { 
    $reportrows = "lots of html"
}
```

Every time this loops $reportrows is set to the html for that row only.

Use `$reportrows .= "some html";` instead which will add each row to $reportrows rather than replace $reportrows with that row.

Edit: Replacing `+=` with `.=`.

Comment: it is not `+=` in PHP for concatenation of strings, it is `.=`

Comment: `+=` is for Java , Javascript ... only in when adding in `PHP`

Comment: Doh, too much java for me. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

I can see why you have errors you are not `concatenating` your result

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php for more detailed explanations

Replace

```
$reportrows = "
```

With

```
$reportrows .= "
```

Full Script

```
function report_bytype($title, $job_set, $job_name) {
    $reporthead = "<h1>$title</h1>
    <table id='report'>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Lead</th>
    <th>Start</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Codes</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Fee</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Invoice</th>
    <th>Paid</th>
    </tr>";

    $reportrows = "";
    while ( $job_name = mysql_fetch_array ( $job_set ) ) {
        $reportrows .= "
    <tr>
    <td class='id'>" . $job_name ['id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['status_id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['lead_id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['date_start'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['code_lead'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['code_hlgd'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['client'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['description'] . "</td>
    <td>&pound;" . $job_name ['fee'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['contact'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['invoice'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['date_inv'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $job_name ['date_paid'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    $reportfoot = "</table>";
    $reporttable = $reporthead . $reportrows . $reportfoot;
    echo $reporttable;
    return $reporttable;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Helen Lee you are welcome ... let know if you have any more issues